# Stored Procedures and Functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, procedures

There are two tables, User (int id) Message (sender_id, adresee_id). The table reports the two foreign key one of which shows the sender and the other on the recipient of the message.

How to set up the function, the procedure and Triger, so that when a user is deleted, messages in the table to place foreign key the user sets the value Null?

Comment: You don't need a trigger. a CASCADING DELETE on the FKs will do.

Comment: If there is a foreign key.  The delete will be blocked until the message is deleted first.  ???